# How to get a function list of a JavaScript file with jEdit's Sidekick on a Mac?

Tags: javascript, macos, jedit

I have a Mac with jEdit 4.5 installed on it, including the Sidekick and the JavaScript plugin from here[1](http://skrul.com/blog/projects/javascript/). Now when I open the Sidekick window, I can choose from two JavaScript parsers (skrul-xml-javascript and skrul-javascript).

However, none of them parses my JavaScript file (the window only shows the document name with "Not parsed" underneath it). When I open a PHP file and choose my PHPParser, it does parse the file and shows clickable PHP function names.

Answer (score 1):

You can install "Ctags SideKick" plugin and choose to use "ctags" parser in sidekick.
And you should install ctags in your system and config it in CtagsSideKick options.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I had to install Exuberant Ctags first, which wasn't as difficult as I thought it was when I wrote the post. This web page helped: [http://www.adamyoung.net/Exuberant-Ctags-OS-X](http://www.adamyoung.net/Exuberant-Ctags-OS-X) though I did it a bit different in order to make it work: I downloaded ctags via [http://ctags.sourceforge.net/](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) in stead of using curl, and had to add a sudo to one of the install commands because it generated an error. Can't give you an upvote unfortunately because of my lack of reputation. :(